# Windows PowerShell.lnk not found

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a Surfacebook (first generation) running Windows 10 Enterprise and joined to my company's active directory domain.  I'm not sure what happened (as best I can tell now updates were installed nor were any GPO applied), but I woke up to a machine that seems to have several core setting reset.  All of my apps that were pinned to my Taskbar and Start Menu were gone, and my app auth tokens were reset, and the two powershell related shortcuts off the context menu of the Start button were no longer mapped to .lnk' files.  I'm trying to get these powershell menu items working again and I'm having no luck.

Doing this:

[image]

Fails with:

[image]

This file was indeed gone.  I don't know what removed this, but I recreated it:

[image]

But still it fails.  I've checked the permissions, I own the directory and .lnk.  I've rebooted and still it didn't work.  Anyone know how to get this back to functional?  And I would love to have a clue as to what might have caused all this to go haywire.

Comment: It should be `Windows PowerShell.lnk`, but not `Windows PowerShell.lnk.lnk`.

Comment: well, well.... i had no idea that lnk file has such odd behavior in Windows Explorer.  ls'ing the dir in powershell indeed showed the double extension.  Even with "how extensions" enabled in Windows Explorer, it still doesn't show .lnk.  Thank you

Comment: That is because of `NeverShowExt` property in the `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\lnkfile` key: `gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\lnkfile`.

Comment: This question belongs on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).